# I want to convert uint value to ether value (solidity)

Tags: solidity

My code:

```
uint money = (msg.sender).balance;
uint myUintValue = 20;
function getEther() public returns(uint) {
    money = money + 1 /* Istead of 1 my uint value*/ ether;
    return money;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to accomplish. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `money = money + myUintValue * (1 ether);`.

Comment: nice, worked for me as well!